# Android How to change OnItemClickListener code in OnClickListener code

Tags: android, onclicklistener, listadapter, onitemclicklistener

I changed my initial Activity in `SherlockActivity` in order to benefit from all the advantages of ABS. and for this I use a `ListAdapterAnSco extends BaseAdapter`.
Now I want to manage`onclick` and `onLongClick` in `getView` of my `ListAdapter`.
I used several combinations but I can not do it.

NB: I use the `SQLiteCursor` to get items

Original OnItemClickListener Code

---

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?>  parent, View v, int position,
                    long id) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),ListPeriode.class);

                SQLiteCursor cr=(SQLiteCursor)parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
                String ansco=cr.getString(cr.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.ANSCO));
                AnSco an=new AnSco(ansco);
                an.setIdan((int)id);

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Année Scolaire: "+an.getAnsco(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                intent.putExtra("ANSCO_ID", an.getIdan());
                intent.putExtra("ANSCO_AN", an.getAnsco());
                cr.close();
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
            }
```

How to change this code in an OnClick methode to do the same work?

My getView

---

```
public View getView(final int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
        final ViewHolder holder;
        if (view == null) {
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.annee_sco_item, null);
            // Locate the TextViews in listview_item.xml
            holder.an = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.ansco_item);
            view.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
        }
        // Set the results into TextViews
        holder.an.setText(listAnsco.get(position).getAnsco());

        // Listen for ListView Item Click
        view.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {


            }
        });

        return view;
    }
```

Comment: did your onClickListener working perfect?

Comment: pass  SQLiteCursor cr to your adapter Constructor.

Comment: where is your onItemClick() located?

Comment: is there any button in listView Row..?

Comment: there is error at this line:

`SQLiteCursor cr=(SQLiteCursor)parent.getItemAtPosition(position);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Extract OnClickListener to seperate class and pass it again

MyClickListener.java

```
 public class MyClickListener implements onItemClickListener
 {
     @override
     public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?>  parent, View v, int position, long id)
     {
         Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),ListPeriode.class);
         SQLiteCursor cr=(SQLiteCursor)parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
         String ansco=cr.getString(cr.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.ANSCO));
         AnSco an=new AnSco(ansco);
         an.setIdan((int)id);
         Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Année Scolaire:"+an.getAnsco(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
         intent.putExtra("ANSCO_ID", an.getIdan());
         intent.putExtra("ANSCO_AN", an.getAnsco());
         cr.close();
         startActivity(intent);
         finish();
     }
}
```

in your adapter remove the

```
   // Listen for ListView Item Click
    view.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
           @Override
           public void onClick(View arg0) {
            }
        });
```

YourActivity.java

```
@override
onCraete(Bundle x)
{
    ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.i.your_list_id);
    listView.setAdapter(new YourAdapter()); 
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new MyClickListener());
}
```

Comment: cannot override onItemClick in onClickListener

Comment: cannot implement onItemClickListener in getView

Comment: Thanks for helping the OnClick Works.
But now i have a new Problem when i click on a list item. 
I will explain it in a new post.

there is error at this line: 

`SQLiteCursor cr=(SQLiteCursor)parent.getItemAtPosition(position);`


`Java.lang.ClassCastException:  

com.android.moyenne.ansco.AnSco cannot be cast to android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor`

Answer (score 0):

you can use :

```
        holder.an.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {

          Intent intent = new Intent(contetx,ListPeriode.class);

            SQLiteCursor cr=(SQLiteCursor)parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
            String ansco=cr.getString(cr.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.ANSCO));
            AnSco an=new AnSco(ansco);
            an.setIdan((int)id);

            Toast.makeText(context, "Année Scolaire: "+an.getAnsco(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            intent.putExtra("ANSCO_ID", an.getIdan());
            intent.putExtra("ANSCO_AN", an.getAnsco());
            cr.close();
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();

        }
    });
```

and context must be passed to class that you extends BaseAdapter

Comment: there is error at this line:

`SQLiteCursor cr=(SQLiteCursor)parent.getItemAtPosition(position);`